Unable to find out the types needed to add to parameter of custom function
I'm using tss-react and MUI package and I'm unable to figure what to set the types for custom function I've written which basically merges all my common styles and the specific styles I want for a component.
Due to this I'm getting TypeScript errors when accessing my classes object. (eg: Property 'colorRed' does not exist on type 'Record<never, string>'.
What types to add in the getUseStyles.ts file so that I get both the types from commonStyles file and my component styles ? (Basically typescript/editor should be able to intellisense when accessing classes object keys like classes.colorRed or classes.colorBlue)
CodeSandbox
// File: Test.tsx
const useStylesHook = getUseStyles(  // Merging component styles and common styles
  (theme) => {
    return {
      colorRed: {
        color: 'red',
      },
      colorBlue: {
        color: 'blue',
      },
    }
})

export default function Test() {
  const { classes, cx } = useStylesHook()
  return (
    <h1 className={cx(classes.colorRed, classes.padding20, classes.colorBlue)}>
      Testing this color
    </h1>
  )
}

// File: commonStyles.ts
export const commonStyles = (theme) => {
  return {
    padding20: {
      paddingTop: '20px',
    },
  }
}

// File: getUseStyles.ts
export const getUseStyles = (
  styles: any, // What types to add here ?
  customStyles?: any,
) => {
  return makeStyles()((theme) => {
    return {
      ...commonStyles(theme),
      ...styles(theme, { ...customStyles }),
    }
  })
}


You can see in this playground that the expected return type of the callback should be Record<string, CSSObject>. However, there's not enough information about the function styles for anyone to advise you on what the type of the parameter customStyles should be — you must decide what it is supposed to do with that argument. If that information answers your question, I can write it as an answer with a little explanation — if not, what did I miss?

At any rate, the question needs to be edited to include a [mre]. Do you need help with that or can you make the edit yourself?

I've already added the codesandbox link

Made little edits on the question as well

We can achieve this by making the key of the record returned by the passed styles function generic such that the information required to infer these properties is not lost.
import { Theme } from '@mui/material'
import { CSSObject } from 'tss-react'
import { commonStyles } from '../commonStyles'
import { makeStyles } from './helpers'

export const getUseStyles = <
  RuleNames extends string,
  CustomStyles extends Record<string, any>,
>(
  styles: (
    theme: Theme,
    customStyles?: CustomStyles,
  ) => Record<RuleNames, CSSObject>,
  customStyles?: CustomStyles,
) => {
  return makeStyles()((theme) => {
    return {
      ...commonStyles(theme),
      ...styles(theme, { ...customStyles } as CustomStyles),
    }
  })
}



It's unclear what the purpose of customStyles is or how it affects the return values of the passed styles function. So that basically doesn't do anything type-wise here currently.
